# Add link to before and after pseudo elements

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

Here I have two blogs, each has an Image, a heading and blog excerpt. When you hover over the blog an overlay appears on the image. I don't want the whole blog to act as a link, What I actually want is I want the heading and overlay both to act as a link. Giving the link to the heading was easy. I have the link to the image but when the overlay covers the image, the link goes off. Just need the overlay to act as a link too.

Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamm_98666/ced7unzm/)

```css
.row {
  position: relative;
  width: 1140px;
  margin: 0 auto 40px;
}

.blog-item-inner {
  background-color: #fbfbfb;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.blog-img-inner {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.blog-post-date {
  position: absolute;
  top: 35px;
  left: 35px;
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  width: 40px;
  height: 35px;
  z-index: 999;
}

.blog-post-date p {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #ffffff;
  line-height: 1;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.blog-post-date span {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 8px;
  color: #ffffff;
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 3px;
}

.blog-title-excerpt {
  padding: 40px 40px 30px;
}

.blog-title-excerpt h3 {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #000000;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.blog-title-excerpt p {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #888888;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.blog-image {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  transition: box-shadow 0.3s linear;
}

.blog-img-inner:before {
  content: "";
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
}

.blog-item-inner:hover .blog-img-inner:before {
  height: 100%;
}

.blog-image .post-meta {
  position: absolute;
  right: 12px;
  bottom: 12px;
  display: block;
  z-index: 15;
}

.blog-content a {
  color: #222222;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Droid Serif", sans-serif;
}

.post-meta {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.post-meta span {
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #c0c0c0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.post-meta span:hover {
  color: #777777;
}

.col6 {
  width: 47.96%;
}

.col {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 4%;
}

.col:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="row clearfix">
  <div class="col col6 blog-items">
    <div class="blog-item-inner clearfix">
      <div class="blog-img-inner">
        <a href="#"><img src="https://image.ibb.co/b8UnFw/blog1.jpg" alt="blog1"></a>
        <div class="blog-post-date">
          <p>18 <span>DEC</span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="blog-title-excerpt">
        <h5 class="fancy-heading-s1"><a href="#">ENDLESS ROAD STARTS</a></h5>
        <p>No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure those who do not know a pulse</p>
        <div class="post-meta">
          <span><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i> 183</span>
          <span><i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i> 57</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col col6 blog-items">
    <div class="blog-item-inner">
      <div class="blog-img-inner">
        <a href="#"><img src="https://image.ibb.co/b8UnFw/blog1.jpg" alt="blog1"></a>
        <div class="blog-post-date">
          <p>12 <span>JUN</span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="blog-title-excerpt">
        <h5 class="fancy-heading-s1"><a href="#">ENDLESS ROAD STARTS</a></h5>
        <p>No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure those who do not know a puIse</p>
        <div class="post-meta">
          <span><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i> 120</span>
          <span><i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i> 18</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the easiest way is to wrap `.blog-img-inner` with `a` and your problem will be solved, check the updated snippet:

```css
.row {
  position: relative;
  width: 1140px;
  margin: 0 auto 40px;
}

.blog-item-inner {
  background-color: #fbfbfb;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.blog-img-inner {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.blog-post-date {
  position: absolute;
  top: 35px;
  left: 35px;
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  width: 40px;
  height: 35px;
  z-index: 999;
}

.blog-post-date p {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #ffffff;
  line-height: 1;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.blog-post-date span {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 8px;
  color: #ffffff;
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 3px;
}

.blog-title-excerpt {
  padding: 40px 40px 30px;
}

.blog-title-excerpt h3 {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #000000;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.blog-title-excerpt p {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #888888;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.blog-image {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  transition: box-shadow 0.3s linear;
}

.blog-img-inner:before {
  content: "";
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
}

.blog-item-inner:hover .blog-img-inner:before {
  height: 100%;
}

.blog-image .post-meta {
  position: absolute;
  right: 12px;
  bottom: 12px;
  display: block;
  z-index: 15;
}

.blog-content a {
  color: #222222;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Droid Serif", sans-serif;
}

.post-meta {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.post-meta span {
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #c0c0c0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.post-meta span:hover {
  color: #777777;
}

.col6 {
  width: 47.96%;
}

.col {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 4%;
}

.col:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="row clearfix">
  <div class="col col6 blog-items">
    <div class="blog-item-inner clearfix">
      <a href="#"><div class="blog-img-inner">
        <img src="https://image.ibb.co/b8UnFw/blog1.jpg" alt="blog1">
        <div class="blog-post-date">
          <p>18 <span>DEC</span></p>
        </div>
      </div></a>
      <div class="blog-title-excerpt">
        <h5 class="fancy-heading-s1"><a href="#">ENDLESS ROAD STARTS</a></h5>
        <p>No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure those who do not know a pulse</p>
        <div class="post-meta">
          <span><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i> 183</span>
          <span><i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i> 57</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col col6 blog-items">
    <div class="blog-item-inner">
      <a href="#"><div class="blog-img-inner">
        <img src="https://image.ibb.co/b8UnFw/blog1.jpg" alt="blog1">
        <div class="blog-post-date">
          <p>12 <span>JUN</span></p>
        </div>
      </div></a>
      <div class="blog-title-excerpt">
        <h5 class="fancy-heading-s1"><a href="#">ENDLESS ROAD STARTS</a></h5>
        <p>No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure those who do not know a puIse</p>
        <div class="post-meta">
          <span><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i> 120</span>
          <span><i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i> 18</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I don't want the whole blog to be a link. I tried that already.

Comment: I didn't tell you to wrap the whole blog, i wrapped the picture only.

Comment: wrap `.blog-img-inner` not `.blog-item-inner`

Answer (score 1):

```css
.row {
  position: relative;
  width: 1140px;
  margin: 0 auto 40px;
}

.blog-item-inner {
  background-color: #fbfbfb;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.blog-img-inner {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.blog-post-date {
  position: absolute;
  top: 35px;
  left: 35px;
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  width: 40px;
  height: 35px;
  z-index: 999;
}

.blog-post-date p {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #ffffff;
  line-height: 1;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.blog-post-date span {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 8px;
  color: #ffffff;
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 3px;
}

.blog-title-excerpt {
  padding: 40px 40px 30px;
}

.blog-title-excerpt h3 {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #000000;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.blog-title-excerpt p {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #888888;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.blog-image {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  transition: box-shadow 0.3s linear;
}

.overly {
  content: "";
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
}

.blog-item-inner:hover .overly {
  height: 100%;
}

.blog-image .post-meta {
  position: absolute;
  right: 12px;
  bottom: 12px;
  display: block;
  z-index: 15;
}

.blog-content a {
  color: #222222;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Droid Serif", sans-serif;
}

.post-meta {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.post-meta span {
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #c0c0c0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.post-meta span:hover {
  color: #777777;
}

.col6 {
  width: 47.96%;
}

.col {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 4%;
}

.col:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="row clearfix">
  <div class="col col6 blog-items">
    <div class="blog-item-inner clearfix">
      <div class="blog-img-inner">
        <a href="#"><img src="https://image.ibb.co/b8UnFw/blog1.jpg" alt="blog1">
         <span class="overly"> </span>
        </a>
        <div class="blog-post-date">
          <p>18 <span>DEC</span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="blog-title-excerpt">
        <h5 class="fancy-heading-s1"><a href="#">ENDLESS ROAD STARTS</a></h5>
        <p>No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure those who do not know a pulse</p>
        <div class="post-meta">
          <span><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i> 183</span>
          <span><i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i> 57</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col col6 blog-items">
    <div class="blog-item-inner">
      <div class="blog-img-inner">
        <a href="#"><img src="https://image.ibb.co/b8UnFw/blog1.jpg" alt="blog1">
        <span class="overly"> </span>
        </a>
        <div class="blog-post-date">
          <p>12 <span>JUN</span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="blog-title-excerpt">
        <h5 class="fancy-heading-s1"><a href="#">ENDLESS ROAD STARTS</a></h5>
        <p>No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure those who do not know a puIse</p>
        <div class="post-meta">
          <span><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i> 120</span>
          <span><i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i> 18</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Appreciate your work but I need to change all the HTML and css again. Thanks for your answer

Comment: Could you point out what's the difference between yours and the accepted answer? And why it might be important / useful?

Answer (score 0):

Simply put some JS on wrapper `<div class="blog-item-inner clearfix" onClick="location.href='http://example.com'">`

```css
.row {
  position: relative;
  width: 1140px;
  margin: 0 auto 40px;
}

.blog-item-inner {
  background-color: #fbfbfb;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.blog-img-inner {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.blog-post-date {
  position: absolute;
  top: 35px;
  left: 35px;
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  width: 40px;
  height: 35px;
  z-index: 999;
}

.blog-post-date p {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #ffffff;
  line-height: 1;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.blog-post-date span {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 8px;
  color: #ffffff;
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 3px;
}

.blog-title-excerpt {
  padding: 40px 40px 30px;
}

.blog-title-excerpt h3 {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #000000;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.blog-title-excerpt p {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #888888;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.blog-image {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  transition: box-shadow 0.3s linear;
}

.blog-img-inner:before {
  content: "";
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
}

.blog-item-inner:hover .blog-img-inner:before {
  height: 100%;
}

.blog-image .post-meta {
  position: absolute;
  right: 12px;
  bottom: 12px;
  display: block;
  z-index: 15;
}

.blog-content a {
  color: #222222;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Droid Serif", sans-serif;
}

.post-meta {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.post-meta span {
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #c0c0c0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.post-meta span:hover {
  color: #777777;
}

.col6 {
  width: 47.96%;
}

.col {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 4%;
}

.col:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="row clearfix">
  <div class="col col6 blog-items">
    <div class="blog-item-inner clearfix" onClick="location.href='#'">
      <div class="blog-img-inner">
        <img src="https://image.ibb.co/b8UnFw/blog1.jpg" alt="blog1">
        <div class="blog-post-date">
          <p>18 <span>DEC</span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="blog-title-excerpt">
        <h5 class="fancy-heading-s1">ENDLESS ROAD STARTS</h5>
        <p>No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure those who do not know a pulse</p>
        <div class="post-meta">
          <span><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i> 183</span>
          <span><i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i> 57</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col col6 blog-items">
    <div class="blog-item-inner">
      <div class="blog-img-inner">
        <a href="#"><img src="https://image.ibb.co/b8UnFw/blog1.jpg" alt="blog1"></a>
        <div class="blog-post-date">
          <p>12 <span>JUN</span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="blog-title-excerpt">
        <h5 class="fancy-heading-s1"><a href="#">ENDLESS ROAD STARTS</a></h5>
        <p>No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure those who do not know a puIse</p>
        <div class="post-meta">
          <span><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i> 120</span>
          <span><i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i> 18</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```